# Do I need a Microsoft 365 account to use Skydrive Pro?

Tags: microsoft-office, onedrive, microsoft-office-2013, office365

I am using Office 2013 (which also installed Skydrive Pro on my machine) but I haven't really understood one thing: do I need an Office 365 account to use Skydrive Pro?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this [technet documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn232145.aspx):

> To support synchronizing document libraries to a user's client workstation with the SkyDrive Pro Windows Sync client, you must have:
>
> - Either
>
>   Office 2013 Standard or Office 2013 Professional Plus.
>
>   An Office 365 subscription that includes the Office 2013 applications.
> - Client workstations running Windows 7 or Windows 8.

So, if not Office 365, you need to have Office installed locally.

Comment: From the link you provided it looks like it is mandatory to have a My Site, which is a feature of SharePoint if I am not mistaken

Comment: Yes that is true! SkyDrive Pro is somewhat [*similar*](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/sharepoint-server-help/what-is-skydrive-pro-HA102822076.aspx) to SharePoint workspace. The goal is to let the user of organization store and share any kind of document while respecting the organization's policies.

Comment: Skydrive itself does not require Office. On it's own it can operate just like Google Drive or any online storage (you can even set it up like a network share). To get the full features out of both Office and Skydrive it is best to have both.

Comment: @Annie So now the question is: what kind of account do I need to be able to access My Site and thus SkyDrive Pro? :)

Comment: @user1301428, I assume that you haven't read the prerequisite section in the link I provided. :) For home user SkyDrive (skydrive.com) suffice the purpose, which is hosted on Microsoft's servers. But if you are looking for SkyDrive accounts for the employees of your organization with your org policies, you first need to have [MOSS](bit.ly/12eMgQ3) 2010 or 2013, foundation (free) or Enterprise (paid) versions configured and other prerequisite mentioned in the link, then you can provide SkyDrive Pro accounts to your business users which would be hosted on your servers instead of MSFT's.

Comment: @Annie You assume wrong, actually, but it doesn't matter. I would suggest you update your answer linking to the correct section of the linked article for future reference.